# CFG that generates $1^*$ is decidable

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, undecidability

I read somewhere that the problem which asks whether or not a CFG $G$ generates $1^*$ is decidable. The proof goes like this:

> $1^* \cap L(G)$ is context free since it is the intersection of a regular language and a CFL, therefore we can test if $1^* \cap L(G)$ is empty since it is decidable to check if the language produced by a CFG is empty. If $1^* \cap L(G)$ is empty, reject, otherwise, accept.

I have doubts however with this proof since it only shows that *some* string in $1^*$ is generated by $G$, but not whether $G$ generates *all* strings in $1^*$.

Moreover, if this proof is correct, we can use the same proof outline under the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ to show that $G$ generates $\Sigma^*$, or that $\Sigma^* \subseteq G$. However, it is known that it is undecidable whether $R \subseteq G$, where $R$ is a regular language, and $G$ is a CFG (by setting $R=\Sigma^*$, and $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$.

But to show that a CFG generates $1^*$ is decidable, the only way I can think of is to use something similar to the proof that it is decidable for a PCP instance to generate some string in $1^*$ (i.e., $w=v$, where $w,v \in 1^*$), i.e. we can check if the CFG has rule $S \rightarrow S1$, then accept. Otherwise, if it has rules of the form $S \rightarrow 1^aS1^b$ such that $a > b$, and rules of the form $S \rightarrow 1^cS1^d$ such that $c < d$, then accept... But is there a simpler way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're confusing two different problems.
The algorithm you are describing shows that the problem of testing whether a CFG generates some string from $1^∗$ is decidable (e.g., see [here](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Ehbarbosa/teaching/cs4330/notes/16-decidable-cfgs.pdf) at page 21). Anyway, the problem of testing whether a CFG generates all the strings of the language $1^∗$ is truly decidable. Consider all production rules to be simple (I mean, no "$|$" on the right), and eliminate all productions including a terminal character different from 1 on the right. Now you have a CFG over a terminal alphabet of a single letter, and then it generates a regular language (see [here](http://www.iasi.cnr.it/%7Eadp/Teach/ALT10/ContextFreeOnSingletonSigma.pdf)). All that remains is to test if two regular languages are equal. Moreover, there are effective procedures to convert a CFG over a one-letter (terminal) alphabet into a regular grammar (e.g., see [here](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/3865/CS015.pdf;sequence=2)).

---

On the last part of your question: the fact that it is undecidable whether $R\subseteq G$, where $R$ is a regular language, and $G$ is a CFL, does not imply that for some specific regular languages you can not decide the inclusion. For example, if $R$ is finite (possibly empty), then testing for $R\subseteq G$ is decidable (see the first link above).